# How to copy one row from a matrix and set it to a row in another matrix in r?

Tags: r, matrix

I have 2 matrices `sampleMatrix` which has **2 rows and 9 columns** and `oldCase` which has **1 row and 9 columns**. Initially the matrices are as follows:

```
sampleMatrix:
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

oldCase:
  Pn       Te VTB TB Sm LC Br XR Dy
   0 38.73447   0  1  1  0  0  1  0
```

I would like to copy the entire row from `oldCase` and set it as the 1st row of `sampleMatrix`. So that I have:

```
sampleMatrix:
     [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    0 38.73447    0    0    1    1    0    1    0
[2,]   NA       NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I could run a loop and copy the column values directly but I was wondering if there is a more concise way of doing this with a special function in r. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: `sampleMatrix[1,] <- oldCase[1,]`

Answer (score 1):

As in the comment by @allan-cameron:

your example in code:

```
sampleMatrix <- matrix(rep(NA, 18), nrow=2)
sampleMatrix
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]   
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

```
oldCase <- matrix(c(0,38.73447,0,1,1,0,0,1,0), nrow=1)
colnames(oldCase) <- c("Pn","Te","VTB","TB","Sm","LC","Br","XR","Dy")
oldCase
```

```
     Pn       Te VTB TB Sm LC Br XR Dy
[1,]  0 38.73447   0  1  1  0  0  1  0
```

the reassignment of row 1 (all columns) of `oldCase` into row 1 (all columns) of `sampleMatrix`:

```
sampleMatrix[1,] <- oldCase[1,]
sampleMatrix
```

```
     [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    0 38.73447    0    1    1    0    0    1    0
[2,]   NA       NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```